# Call & Meeting Bot Teams, Speech

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, speech-to-text, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a classical conversational bot (MS BotFramework) in Teams.
I would like to do some vocal queries to the Bot (ask some questions) and that one has to answer by text/cards in the conversation.

The aim of the Bot is when it detects a Keyword, it transcribes the question into the conversation and answers it.

Since the service SPEECH is not available in Teams yet, I tried to do a call and meeting bot but I couldn't readapt the code on my own Bot. I don't know how to manage the audio stream.
I hear about app-hosted-media and I try to look on that side but I really don't know how it works.

So, I would like to know if someone has already worked on it or if it is possible to achieve what I want to do with the bot (in Teams) ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include links to any documentation or samples you're following, and also include code and screenshots if applicable

Comment: Are you still working on this?